# Formatting dates laravel using protected $dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel

I did some searching around for a way to format a date displayed on my view. I found that if insert the field into the protected $dates array under the model I am able to manipulate the date as needed. However now when I want to make a new insertion into the database I get

```
Unexpected Date Format
```

Here is what I have in my model:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'address','caption', 'video', 'visibility', 'image', 'publish_at', 'link'];

protected $dates = ['publish_at'];
```

Inside my view:

```
    <p class = "day">
        {{$event->publish_at->format('d')}}
    </p>


    <p class = "month">
        {{$event->publish_at->format('M')}}
    </p>
```

I tried to format the date again before it is saved doing this:

```
$date = new ElephantCalender(array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'description'  => $request->get('description'),
        'caption'  => $request->get('caption'),
        'address'  => $request->get('address'),
        'link'  => $request->get('link'),
        'visibility'  => $request->get('visibility'),
        'publish_at'  => $request->get('publish_at')->format('yyyy-mm-dd')
    ));

    $date->save();
```

This tells me that I can't use format() on a string. Is there another way to get the date to the correct format to be submitted to the table?

Comment: I think Eloquent will convert a Carbon object into the right date format, so maybe you could `'publish_at' => new Carbon($request->get('publish_at'))`

Comment: This works just fine. Thanks alot @Rudie.. Can you put this into an answer so i can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent uses `Carbon` to create date objects. It can also use Carbon to store date objects into the db according to the configured date format.

This should work:

```
'publish_at' => new Carbon($request->get('publish_at'))
```

The input format is very important. Like this, you'll let Carbon or PHP decide how to parse the input date string. Some date formats are ambiguous: 11/7/2015 might mean 11 Jul or 7 Nov. To be absolutely certain, you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat`, as @volkinc suggested. The resulting object will be formatted by Eloquent, in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about formatting date from get(..)

use

```
$tempT = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '10-16-2003')->format('Y-m-d');
```

or something like

```
$d = new DateTime('10-16-2003');

$timestamp = $d->getTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
$tempT = $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2003-10-16
```

As you can use  $tempT in a query